# Svn duplicates disk space used by a directory?

Tags: svn, diskspace

I'm using svn. 
I've a directory called addons that I've done commit to svn, than I did checkout.

Before Svn, the directory occupied 913M:

```
# du -chs *
913M    addons
```

After doing checkout to a directory addons_svn:

```
# svn co http:..../addons addons_svn
# du -chs *
1.9G    addons_svn
```

It is normal this difference of space used ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. SVN holds a copy of the versioned files in order to be able to quickly check for changes.

Taken from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SvnSetup (markup by me):

> At the time of writing, a GCC snapshot takes around 320Mb of space. With Subversion 1.3, a typical GCC working copy takes between 640Mb and 700Mb of of space (depends on the filesystem, eg. reiserfs is better than ext3). **The "wasted" space is because SVN keeps a double copy of each and every file to let common operations be totally offline and thus blazingly fast svn diff svn status etc.)**. Subversion 1.4 will probably have a way to compress this copy so to waste less space (or disable it altogether, but you probably don't want that).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which version of SVN you're using.

SVN maintains the last revision of each file so it can perform operations like diff and status quickly. It also means it can quickly generate deltas to upload without talking to the server. Unfortunately, it means it requires twice as much space to checkout a directory. On modern discs this isn't seen as a problem, source held in a repo is small compared to the gigabytes of storage even consumer SSDs provide. Note that this is not a cost to the network transfer as the files are downloaded once and written out twice - once for you to work on, once for SVN to see what the file was before you edited it.

Old versions of SVN stored these 'working base' files in hidden directories called .svn, one per directory.

[SVN 1.7 uses a SQLite DB to store these files](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng), the location of this db is usually at the root checkout level.